# How to fetch Omniture 1*1 image request parameters using TestNG and selenium Grid

Tags: selenium-rc, testng, adobe-analytics

I am new to selenium and TestNG . Can any one give me some example to fetch 1*1 Omniture image request parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just want to see what information was passed in the parameter? You could use something like Charles to see all the details. Its a simple pixel request, so you can grab that URL and parse it out if you need a little more info. The image request will always contain /b/ss/ so it should be easy to grab.

Comment: Thanks a Lot For your Reply,  i am currently using Charles Tool for fetching 1*1 image  request and their corresponding   omniture response manually. But i want to Automate the URL using Selenium Grid/RC and TestNG . Can You Provide some Code of TestNG  like how to fetch the omniture response coming from desired URL.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question, the following appears to be a solution:
http://samaitra.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/http-profiler-using-selenium-to-track.html